# Placeholder for a listener class extending ApplicationLifecycleListener

Tags: java, weblogic

I have a third party class which extends ApplicationLifecycleListener which I have added in my weblogic-application.xml file as a listener .This class loads certain data during server startup

Snippet of weblogic-application.xml

```
 <listener>
       <listener-class>com.XX.XX.XXX</listener-class>
 </listener>
```

Now my project structure have changed now instead of ear we build war file. Can anyone let me know where to keep this piece of configuration I mean in which configuration file I can add this listener as weblogic-application.xml do not exist anymore as we migrated from ear to war.

I can see web.xml and weblogic.xml as a placeholder which is inside web-inf folder to keep this .But adding here did not work

Note : This listenere class is a third party API

Answer (score 1):

You can add a listener in your "web.xml" like spring does.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

You can also write your own class which must implement the

```
javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
```

interface to work as a listener. Listeners are executed in the order they are defined in the web.xml .

We use this pattern to create webservice clients in the servlet context. Works fine :)

Comment: But as i mentioned it is not a normal listener it is ApplicationLifecycleListener . do you still think that will work

Comment: Yes, got it. But because the ApplicationLifecycleListener is very special to weblogic or application server in general, the ContextLoaderListener is my best guess for you. You can use the "contextInitiliazed" and "contextDestroy" method for your belongings. It should be very similar to weblogics "postStart" and "postStop" method.

Answer (score 0):

if your ApplicationLifecycleListener implements ServletContextListener then you can define the same class in web.xml as a listener. like Stephan Watermeyer suggested.[link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/app_events.html#178122)